# How can I use dbReadTable to have a certain class for my variables

Tags: r, r-dbi

When reading in data like this:

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
Id_test <- Id(schema = "Eelke", table = "test")
raw <- dbReadTable(con, Id_test)
```

One of the variables is read in as numeric and it loses some of the zero's before which I do need.

How can I make sure to read the variable in as either chr or factor?

Comment: if the length of the numbers are always the same you can pad using `str_pad` functin

Comment: Thanks Mislav, this workaround is very useful, however I have numbers of 13 & 14 long..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbReadTable()` will return whatever the database driver (in this case *odbc*) returns. There's no override.

You haven't supplied much detail, but it seems that ODBC somehow incorrectly returns a character column as numeric. One way to "convince" it to stop this behavior is to create an SQL query that composes a string that cannot be mistaken for a number:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT CONCAT('#', id_column, '#')")
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it indeed!